# OAuth2AuthorizedClientService implementations cache tokens per client principal

Tags: spring-security

When configuring WebClient with a ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction, we've found that both implementations provided for OAuth2AuthorizedClientService cache tokens in a way that make them only able to be used by the current client.

I have an Rest API setup and configured with OAuth2 authentication that can have a variety of clients.  This API makes a downstream call to another API using its own client credentials.  What we found was that the tokens cached in the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService are only usable if the same client calls my API.  This means that if 2 different clients call my API, a new token will be requested for the second call, even if a perfectly valid token is already saved. This presents an issue since the downstream resource server is rate limited and my API is generally called by a number of different clients.

Looking for a way to configure things so that the tokens in this case are cached globally for all clients to use.  I was able to solve this by writing my own OAuth2AuthorizedClientService, but my preference would be to use OTB Spring to do this if at all possible.

I've tried configuring WebClient and the ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction a number of ways, but looking at the internals of the implementations of OAuth2AuthorizedClientService, I'm not sure there is anything out of the box that will satisfy my requirement.

Originally I had WebClient configured like this:

```java
@Bean
protected WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    OAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler = new RemoveAuthorizedClientOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler((clientRegistrationId, principal, attributes) -> authorizedClientService.removeAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, principal.getName()));
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
 
    oauth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    oauth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("oauth2");
    oauth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.setAuthorizationFailureHandler(oAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler);
 
    return builder.apply(oauth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
}
```

After looking closer at Spring's provided implementations, my only solution was to write my own OAuth2AuthorizedClientService:

```java
public final class IgnorePrincialOAuth2AuthorizedClientService implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientService {

    private static final Authentication ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("anonymous", "anonymousUser", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));

    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService delegate;

    public IgnorePrincialOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService delegate) {
        Assert.notNull(delegate, "delegate cannot be null");
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends OAuth2AuthorizedClient> T loadAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, String principalName) {
        return delegate.loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, Authentication principal) {
        delegate.saveAuthorizedClient(toAnonymousPrincipal(authorizedClient), ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAuthorizedClient(String clientRegistrationId, String principalName) {
        delegate.removeAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId, ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION.getName());
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizedClient toAnonymousPrincipal(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        return new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient.getClientRegistration(), ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION.getName(), authorizedClient.getAccessToken(), authorizedClient.getRefreshToken());
    }

}
```